# If-else and self question

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

```
int age == 3;

if (age == 2)
NSLog(@"2");

if (age == 4)
NSLog(@"4");

if (age == 3)
NSLog(@"3");
```

I was wondering what's the point of putting `else if`instead of having three if statements.

```
for (GameObject *character in listOfGameObjects) {
if (character.myGameObjectType == kPowerUpTypeHealth) { 
                characterHealth = 100.0f;
        } 
     }
```

This is in the Viking.m file. `character` and `self`(viking) both have the instance variable, setter and getter method `characterHealth`. If I want to make Viking's health equal to a hundred do I have to write `self.characterHealth = 100.0f;`to make sure the health isn't added to `character`? Or is what I already have fine?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `==`, not `=` for testing equality!  The statement `if (age = 2)` **assigns** 2 to `age` and then tests if it's non-zero, which it always is.

Comment: Whoops, totally forgot that without Xcode's warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that if you have 3 if statements, all of those conditions will be checked, since age can only have 1 value, you should use

```
if (age == 2)  //You need the double equals, to check for equality, if you use one equals it will assign the value and the if statement will always be true.

else if (age == 3)

else if (age == 4)
```

so after one of those conditions is met, the other conditions will NOT be checked, saving processing time.

Regarding the self, it will work both ways, however if characterHealth is a `@property`, using self will assing it using the `@synthetize setter`, so if you have it declared as `retain` it will increase the `retain` count by 1, if you assign it without self it wont increase the `retain` count. Although since you are assigning it a `primitive` it doesn't matter in this case, only `objects` have a retain count.

Answer (score 1):

Your first snippet will always log 2, 4 and 3, so it's very different from an if/else if/else if sequence (which would always log 2, and nothing else).

If you had written it with `if (a == 2)`, then the difference with an if/else is that your code will always run the three tests, while the one with `else`s could skip some. (Also consider the `switch` statement.)

For your second question, it's safe to omit the `self`. But if it looks ambiguous/confusing to you, do put it. It doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

They are 2 different things. If you have an if statement followed by 4 else if's then only one out of those 4 conditions would be executed. For instance if you have

```
     int age = 2;

 if (age == 2){
     NSLog(@"2");
 }else if (age <=2 ){
    NSLog(@"<=2");
 }else if (age >=2 ){
        NSLog(@">=2");
 }
```

The result of the above code would be `2`. This is because the first condition was true so we dont need to check others. However if you are dealing with a bunch of if's, say

```
    int age = 2;

if (age == 2){
    NSLog(@"2");
}
if (age <=2 ){
   NSLog(@"<=2");
}
if (age >=2 ){
       NSLog(@">=2");
}
```

The result of that would be `2 <=2 >=2`. In essence all statements were executed.

Answer (score 0):

In this case if and else if don't make a difference.  Since the conditions are exclusive consider this example:

```
if(age > 15)
{ 
    NSLog(@"over 15");
}

if (age < 17)
{
    NSLog(@"under 17");
}
```

This will print
over 15
under 17

Use else if to only print one of these.

When accessing a property self is assumed.  It wouldn't change character because you haven't specified character.characterHealth.

Answer (score 0):

Flow control style is the subject of many heated quasi-religious arguments ;)

You'd normally use `else if` in a situation where you have to catch a finite number of cases before a catch-all `else` case. Say if you wanted to check if age was 3, 4 or anything else else:

```
if (age == 3) {
} else if (age == 4) {
} else {
}
```